# Azure API gateway and app service, concurrency limitation?

Tags: azure-api-management

Have an odata api endpoint hosted in App Service behind API Management Gateway, but getting concurrency call issues, trying to identify where the problem occurs. We use a standard tier of API gateway. Is there a concurrent call limit? Sorry trying to scan through documentation didn't find one straight answer.

One more question, what is the simplest way to track the request and response the API gateway generates? Thanks

Comment: What kind of concurrency call issues are you seeing?  Does the request reach the backend? What status code are you getting back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the header `Ocp-Apim-Trace: true` to a request will return a link to a complete trace of the request and respond.  This only works if you are using a subscription key for an administrator user.

Comment: The request did reach backend, it is getting 200 in most cases but some 400, issue is there is another gateway between client and azure so we need to track what azure API management get and what did it send back, no adding APIm trace is not a solution here since it is native app it's hard to debug the response. Thanks for help out! Is there a simple way, e.g. File log I can enable on apim to see request and response?

Comment: @TOMMYWANG  Can you change the URL that the other Gateway talks to?  If so, you can use Runscope to sit between the first Gateway and Azure API Management.  If not, you could use the Log2EventHub policy to see the requests that APIM receives.  It's not the simplest thing to setup but the details are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample

Comment: Thanks. The link was very informative, I will try it out, leave this thread open if I ran into issues :)